# Routing Audio signal between apps

Tags: audio, audio-recording

does anyone know how I can route audio signals between apps?
I want to play something on a synth app and route and record it with a looper in parallel. The looper normally would use the built in mic as input and has no option to choose an other app instead.
I could not find any solution for this on google.
Thank you for you help in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I record internal audio?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/how-can-i-record-internal-audio)

Comment: Hey Robert, yes and no. It would help if someone could give me an example of an app which would do this + recording of internal sound alone is not the goal. The redirecting to the other app is important.

Comment: Unless the answers of the linked question are outdated this doesn't seem possible. Usually an audio system like Android uses has no routing as transmission of audio between apps is not intended. If an app wants to route audio to another app both apps have to implement an own interface for sending/receiving the data.

Comment: Ahh, okay, got it. Thank you!